# How to check that ssh will launch on restart?

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I want to restart an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS machine through ssh. I do not have physical access to that machine.

How can I make sure that the ssh service starts automatically on boot so that I can connect again after restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a terminal run `systemctl list-unit-files | grep ssh` and if the service says `enabled` it should start back up when the system reboots.

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep ssh
ssh.service                                                      enabled        
ssh@.service                                                     static         
sshd.service                                                     enabled        
ssh.socket                                                       disabled
```

And you can check the current status of `ssh` by running `systemctl | grep ssh`

```
$ systemctl | grep ssh
ssh.service    loaded active     running   OpenBSD Secure Shell server
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reload command.  What this does is leave access to ssh while it goes through the process testing your changes in your sshd config file.  If there are problems it will error out, so you can fix them.  Then you go through the process until everything loads fine.  After it reloads, then you can run a restart.

However, if you still feel you need another way, you can run another ssh daemon on a different port, that you can bring up and down and set to start up on reboot as well, and after everything is configured with the ssh you wanted to configure works, you can disable the backup daemon from restarting on bootup.